# My View is not found initial with Caliburn.Micro but when changing tab it works

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I made an example of the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SInnovations.WindowsAzure.Publisher.Views.TabsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <TabControl x:Name="Items" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- this is the header template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

In my ShellView I have:

```
<Views:TabsView cal:Bind.Model="{Binding TabsViewModel}" />
```

that maps to its model on the shellviewmodel.

```
public TabsViewModel TabsViewModel { get; set; }
```

and the TabsViewModel looks like this:

```
public class TabsViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public void Add(BaseTabViewModel testTabViewModel)
    {
        Items.Add(testTabViewModel);            
        ActivateItem(testTabViewModel);           
    }
}
public class BaseTabViewModel : Screen
{
    private bool _isEnabled;

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_isEnabled)) return;
            _isEnabled = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsEnabled);
        }
    }
}
```

**My Problem** is that when the UI spins up, i add two viewmodels to the tabViewModel, the view is just writing out the type "SInnovations.WindowsAzure.Publisher.ViewModels.TestTabViewModel" and first when I click one of the tabs it update the view to the content of my "TestTabView.xaml"

```
 TabsViewModel.Add(new TestTabViewModel());
 TabsViewModel.Add(new TestTabViewModel());
```

#### Update

My OnActivate is not called though on the BaseTabViewModel

```
protected override void OnActivate()
{
    base.OnActivate();
}
```

Any reason to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a ContentControl solved it.

```
            <!--<Views:TabsView cal:Bind.Model="{Binding TabsViewModel}" />-->
            <ContentControl x:Name="TabsViewModel"></ContentControl>
```

Another guy having exactly the same setup asked here

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/435779

Just needed conductWith(this) on the child viewmodel.

```
        TabsViewModel = new TabsViewModel();
        TabsViewModel.ConductWith(this);
```

in the shell contstructor.